# how to convert array to JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, android, arrays, json, cordova

We developing Phone-Gap app.We need Get `CSV` file data and into `sqlite` DB.We get data [FILE API in phoneGap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileReader) 
We code like this

```
function readDataUrl(file) {



    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log("Read as data URL");

        console.log(evt.target.result);

    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function readAsText(file) {

    console.log('in readAsText'+file);

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        ss=evt.target.result;
        alert(ss);
          console.log("Read as text");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

We get Like this [image]

But this format not insert into `sqLite` DB .We need `JSON` data.

We need like this

```
       [  
            {  
                "FOC":1,
                "price":0,
                "customerid":"ARU005",
                "lineamount":0,
                "items":"W.D.M.W HERBAL 250Mx24",
                "tdate":"2015-4-7",
                "qty":8,
                "orderId":"Himansu16:23:20020",
                "umo":"CTN",
                "descriptions":"100mg",
                "bookorder":"ABCARU0052320"
            }
        ]


    [  
    {  
        "TOTALAMOUNT":1000,
        "DISCOUNT":1,
        "NETAMOUNT ":900,
        "VAT":0,
        "GROSSAMOUNT ":900,
        "BOOKORDER":"ABCARUOO7451",
        "CUSTOMERID":"ARU007",
        "TODAYDATE":"2015-4-7"
    }
]
```

Please guide me.We get data form CSV file.NOW We need getting data convert into JSON so Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Use `JSON.parse` function of javascript:

With your variable:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(evt.target.result);
```

For more check [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

If you are getting an array in the result then you can use: `JSON.stringify(evt.target.result);`

Comment: When we tried  var jsonData = JSON.parse(evt.target.result); alert(jsonData ); alert not printed Please help me

Comment: For alert to view the data use : `alert(JSON.stringify(evt.target.result));`

Comment: yes when we placed alert(JSON.stringify(evt.target.result)); We got Alert as my image data in my question  with " ";

Comment: @PavanAlapati JSON.parse function make it as object that's why, may be, it is nor alerting.

Answer (score 0):

This [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data) can help you.

from linked post you have two options:

1. Use [jquery-csv](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/) Plugin to parse CSV file.
2. Second option is to write function in javascript (Code is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1293163/3354492)) that will parse the CSV file.

Now choice is yours. You may need to dig into these two options to get the correct results as the CSV file content you showed in Question is bit different and Uncommon.